# Use all from a module, but exclude specific one

Tags: rust

I have a lot of re-exports across my code for convenience, but sometimes I'd like to specifically exclude something to avoid a possible naming confusion or conflicting implementation.

Coming from Scala, I would expect the below to NOT compile (I don't want it to), because the `Bar as _` syntax would drop Bar from the import. However, this still compiles. Is there some rust syntax that does what I want?

```
pub mod stuff{
    pub struct Foo{}
    pub struct Bar{}
}

pub mod other_stuff{
    use super::stuff::{*, Bar as _};
    pub struct Baz{
        foo : Foo,
        bar : Bar
    }
}
```

To be clear, I want to `use` everything from `stuff` EXCEPT for `Bar`. (obvs in this case I could just import `Foo`, but my actual use cases have lots of imports and I don't want to itemize all-but-one of them.)

EDIT: I'd still like to know how to do this, but I realize I'd made an odd mistake in my motivating example. Posting here for context and in case anyone else is tripped on the same thing. Basically, what I actually had looked like:

```
pub mod stuff{
    pub struct Foo;
    pub struct Bar;
}

pub mod yet_more_stuff{
    use super::stuff::*;
    pub struct Bar{}
    pub struct Baz{
        pub foo : Foo,
        pub bar : Bar
    }
    impl Baz{
        pub fn new() -> Self{
            Self{
                foo : Foo,
                bar : Bar
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code block does NOT compile; because I defined `Bar` in one place as `struct Bar;` and in another as `struct Bar{}`, the type in `Baz` was `yet_more_stuff:Bar` but the value constructed in `Baz::new()` was `stuff::Bar`. This looked like it was conflicting rather than taking precedence as the answer below describes.

Comment: Don't do that. Use [`auto-import`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#auto-import).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntax in Rust for that.

Do notice, however, that specific imports always take precedence over glob imports, so if you have `use stuff::*` and `use other_stuff::Bar` where `stuff` also contains `Bar`, there will be no conflict and the `Bar` from `other_stuff` will always be chosen. There will only be a conflict between two glob imports or two specific imports.

In general, however, glob imports are discouraged and it's better to use specific imports, especially if you don't want to import *everything*.

Comment: I've found specific imports to be a lot of boiler plate, so what I've tried doing is creating modules that re-export the stuff I want to import everywhere (`itertools`, `HashMap`, `Display`, etc), and doing glob imports from those. Does that sound like a bad pattern to you? https://github.com/edwardpeters/organizing_rust/blob/main/src/lib.rs illustrates what I'm describing if it's helpful.

Comment: @EdwardPeters If you need to use those a lot of times, that's a viable approach.

Comment: And yeah, I realized the precedence thing right before you answered - fun fact, `struct Bar{}` shadows `struct Bar;` as a type but `Bar{}` does not then shadow `Bar` as a value.

Comment: @EdwardPeters That's because `struct Bar;` creates actually _two_ things - a type and a constant - with the same name, but they leave in different namespaces, so are imported differently.

Comment: @EdwardPeters In the same way, [`fn Bar()` shadows the tuple constructor of `struct Bar()` but not the type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ebe9d72445d65ebca5117dd6d4068b8).